# leaflet.draw: typeerror (t is null) on edit click

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using leafle.draw with leaflet_1.0.

Draw a polygon (it looks like this http://img.dothesights.com/2016-09-14_160226.png)
and (after end drawing) I click 'Edit layers' and get an error "TypeError: t is null" (looks like this http://img.dothesights.com/2016-09-14_160707.png)

and then breaks all

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, make sure you include your leaflet version, use the source build (`leaflet-src.js`), and provide a stack trace; that should help make it clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

leaflet.draw does not support leaflet 1.0 yet. Try with leaflet 0.7

See [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#important)